# Linearization of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, linearization

Find a linearization of the differential equation for $x$ near $0$.

$$x''(t) + x(t) e^{0.05x} = 0$$

Not sure what to do here. My book isn't any help either..

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: To "linearize" a differential equation means to replace every non-linear function of the dependent variable by a linear approximation.  Of course, a linear approximation close to one point may not be an approximation close to another point- that's why it say "for x near 0".  **At** x= 0, $xe^{0.05x}= (0)(e^0)= 0$.  The derivative is $e^{0.05x}+ 0.05xe^{0.05x}$ which is $e^0+ 0.05(0)e^0= 1$ at x= 0.  The tangent line to $y= xe^{0.05x}$ at x= 0 is $y= x+ 1$.  Replacing $xe^{0.05t}$ by that gives $x''(t)+ x+ 1= 0$.

Comment: @user247327 Why is that a comment

Comment: so going by that my linear differential equation would end up being x''(t) + 0.05x'(t)e^0.05t + e^0.05t ?

Comment: idk how you got + 1 but the answer is x'' +x = 0

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ is small, $e^{0.05x} \approx 1$, therefore we can make the approximation

$$ x'' + x = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x’$. Then $y’=x’’=-x e^{ax}$ where $a=0.05$. Now you have a 2 dimensional dynamical system that can be linearised about x, y and written in matrix form as the linear system 
$$\left( \begin{array}{r}y’ \\ x’ \end{array} \right)= \left[ \begin{array}{rr} 0 & -e^{ax}(1+ax)\\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right] \left( \begin{array}{r}y \\ x \end{array}   \right)$$

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was asking

Comment: I think it could well be. One of the tags the OP used is “nonlinear-system”. If that has anything to do with control and dynamical systems (“nonlinear systems”), this is a standard way there to make a lower dimensional nonlinear system into a higher dimensional linear system.

Comment: It's a fine interpretation, although the answer key says otherwise (look at his comments)

Comment: Ah, I see. I’ll let the answer remain anyway if some future user comes here searching using the words in the title of thus thread or the tags.